# What kind of slang is "Crêpe-de-Chine-Vorlesungen"?

Tags: history, slang

Several people say the mathematician David Hilbert gave "Crêpe-de-Chine-Vorlesungen'' in the 1930s.  The phrase means that the audience at the lectures included many somewhat wealthy people and specifically refers to the women's clothes.  The phrase is rare on the internet today and seems to be only historical.

**Can anyone tell me whether this use of "Crêpe de Chine" was a common slang in the 1920s and 1930s?  Was it specifically academic slang?**

To be clear, I know what the phrase means, and Michael Brenner and Detlev Claussen both explain it in quotes below.

I am asking whether it was popular slang, or academic slang, or really not common at all in Germany of the 1920s and 30s.

As to sources it is possible that all the references specifically to Hilbert trace back to Hel Braun's posthumously published autobiography  *Eine Frau und die Mathematik 1933–1940. Der Beginn einer wissenschaftlichen Laufbahn*.

But also Michael Brenner's book *The Renaissance of Jewish Culture in Weimar Germany* says

> Martin Buber helped to realize an important goal set by Rosenzweig:
>   to attract not only schoolgirls but also the "crepe-de-chine"
>   audience, the upper-middle class of the Frankfurt Westend."

And I find one passage written in the 1920s in *Franz Rosenzweig: Der Mensch und Sein Werk: Briefe und Tagebücher* p. 869:

> wollte ich das Crepe-de-Chine-Publikum bei der Stange halten

Here is another suggestion that it may have been academic slang.  German historian, Detlev Claussen, says in his book *Theodor Adorno - One Last Genius*:

> [Frankfurt] university likewise developed the custom of what were
>   known as crêpe-de-chine lectures. Dr. Wiesengrund’s inaugural lecture
>   is supposed to have been one such occasion. It is said that the crème
>   de la crème turned out to hear him.

He does not really say Frankfurt University coined the term, but Rosenzweig quoted above was in Frankfurt.

While Braun could conceivably have gotten the phrase from Rosenzweig (or Buber) it is not at all likely given her interests and the way she spent her time.  If it originated with Rosenzweig it must have passed through a few hands before reaching her.  And she uses it as if it were common coin, with no explanation at all of what it means.

I did find others but it is hard to relocate them now since naturally a search of "Crêpe de Chine" gets lots of irrelevant hits.

Comment: Can you give references? In my academic career I have seen several cases, where obscure phrases could be traced to one single remark!

Comment: " a soft fine or sheer clothing crepe especially of silk". Doesn't this mean a soft talk which doesn't require you to think that much (TED-style) not as much as a talk properly to mathematicians would do?

Comment: @c.p. No, that is not what she meant.  In context, it is clear Hel Braun was not suggesting the great Hilbert should not have given these lectures.  She says she wishes she could have heard them.  And she probably means the lectures which became the book *Anschauliche Geometrie* which is semi-popular but also great math.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty That quote should be in the question, then. Have you asked in French Stackexchange?

Comment: @c.p. Which quote?  Do you want me to quote Hel Braun saying she wished she could have heard the lectures?

Comment: At least. But rather where it appears with the compound *Vorlesungen*. If you say it refers to women's cloths, maybe they determined a social class. It's hard to guess, and doesn't seem really to be related to German.

Comment: I'd agree with the interpretation that the phrase refers to the clothing that a specific social class of the time liked to wear (meaning, clothes made of crêpe de chine or Chinaseide). A phrase like "Latte-Macchiato-Mütter" seems comparable.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Thanks.  Do you know who at that time used this phrase to refer to the people who typically wore such clothes?  That is my question.

Comment: @c.p. I have quoted two Germans using the phrase: one current historian and one theologian from the 1920s.  I do not ask what it means, since the historian explains it perfectly.  I am asking how widely Germans used this slang.

Comment: Why do you ask this superspecific question actually?

Comment: @äüö I ask because i wonder how widespread an expression this was in the 1930s, and especially whether it was academic slang or more general than that.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty: yes, but why?

Comment: @äüö Because I want to understand what Hel Barun means to convey in this passage, and when she uses a phrase which seems unusual today I wonder why she chose it.  What association did she have with this expression? course I cannot explain Hel Braun to you here.  You could read her autobiography, the title is in the question.  Anyway, one step towards telling what an author would express by a given choice of words is to understand how that given expression was used at the time.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty Most likely it was rarely used academic slang. Never heard my grandparents using that expression, nor heard it in all those old movies from the 1930/40s. Just creme-de-la-creme is well-known.

Comment: ... or just a journalistic term used in that decade for describing a touch of luxury. Search for "Chinakrepp" on https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nigliche_Hoheit

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Wait, is "Latte-Macchiato-Mütter" a real slang term? Or did you just make it up as an analogy. (As a side note, "crepe-de-chine-Publikum" sounds to me like it indicates a *leisure class*, not just people with money, while "Latte-Macchiato-Mütter" sounds to me like well-to-do professional women. What do you think?)

Comment: @MissMonicaE Yes, "Latte-Macchiato-Eltern", specificially "Latte-Macchiato-Mutter" [is an actual phrase](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latte_macchiato#Kulturelle_Bedeutung).

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck The Germans really do have a word for everything. :)

Comment: @MissMonicaE Actually, the term already made it into the Duden as "Latte-Macchiato-Mama". The [quote from the "Szenewörterbuch"](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/newsletter/Duden-Newsletter-190310) also describes the derogatory way it's mostly used. Some "real life examples" are [this blog entry](http://www.berlinfreckles.de/kind_und_kegel/bin-ich-eine-latte-macchiato-mutter), [this "SZ" article](http://sz-magazin.sueddeutsche.de/texte/anzeigen/36538/) or [this "Welt" article](https://www.welt.de/vermischtes/article135976734/Ach-das-bisschen-Kinder-ist-doch-kein-Problem.html).

Comment: I'm not sure about how often this was used in German academia in 1900, but that's the name of an expensive type of fabric:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%AApe_%28textile%29#Entry_from_Encyclop.C3.A6dia_Britannica_Eleventh_Edition_.281911.29
It looks like this was introduced in the late 19th century, and might just not be academia, slang, or even strictly German.

Answer (score 1):

Edwardian fiction writer Amy Josephine Baker (* 1895) titled her book “[The Crêpe de Chine Wife](http://www.worldcat.org/title/crepe-de-chine-wife/oclc/316195236/editions)” in London in 1924.  Her concept might perhaps via some feuilletons have had some ephemeral influence in the German Bildungsbürgertum with regard to financially resembling the old francophonic aristocracy.

Today's Germans associate Chinakrepp merely with crafting pupils in public schools.  Way too common and too young to denote any sociological noblesse.

Comment: It's asked, however, what the meaning in the early 20th Century was.